# BottomNavigationView with item background covers FAB

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I'm using the new BottomNavigationView with a floating action button on top of it.. and it was working fine until I added item background to bottom navigation view, now the navigation view covers the FAB although the FAB has more elevation than the navigation view..

Here's my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:translationZ="0dp"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:translationZ="16dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/navigation"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_menu_timeline_icon" />
```

and here's what I want
[image: What I want]

But here's what I get:
[image: Floating isn't visible]

Comment: can you add na image with the problema?

Comment: Done, Check the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the bottom navigation below the FAB? This link might be useful: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/issues/38

Also you might want to check the standard elevation for FAB which is "6dp" for resting and "12dp" for pressed state .The link https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android